# Understanding an angular routing fall through problem

Tags: angular, routes

I have an angular 14 app with routing and I've been having an issue with one of the routes.  The app routing module defines these routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'pathone/:uuid',
    canLoad: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./pathone/pathone.module').then((m) => m.PathoneModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'pathtwo/:uuid',
    canLoad: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./pathtwo/pathtwo.module').then((m) => m.PathtwoModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'paththree/:uuid',
    canLoad: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./paththree/paththree.module').then((m) => m.PaththreeModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'welcome',
    loadChildren: () => import('./welcome/welcome.module').then((m) => m.WelcomeModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'pathone',
    canLoad: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./pathone/pathone.module').then((m) => m.PathoneModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'pathtwo',
    canLoad: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./pathtwo/pathtwo.module').then((m) => m.PathtwoModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'paththree',
    canLoad: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./paththree/paththree.module').then((m) => m.PaththreeModule),
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'welcome' },
];
```

All of the modules have their own routing module, but they are all the generic cli generated one, where the path '' loads the component.

Here's the problem:  `http://localhost:4200/pathtwo/1` loads the pathtwo module and `http://localhost:4200/paththree/1` loads the paththree module, but `http://localhost:4200/pathone/1` is bypassing the AuthGuard and redirecting to the welcome module, which makes window.location.href equal /welcome instead of /pathone/1. The AuthGuard stores the window.location.href before redirecting the user to login if not logged in, which may not be the ideal way to do this but works fine for the other two paths.  I know pathone/1 was matching the welcome entry because the AuthGuard wasn't running.  Had the same issue when deployed to the server, not just when using localhost.

Multiple sets of eyes have looked at the code and the setup for all three is identical.  No typos or anything in the real code.  The reason for both pathone/:uuid and plain pathone is that the user might try to type in pathone without the route parameter, so I wanted that condition to be caught.  But that should never happen, so I put it after the welcome module.

I eliminated the problem by changing the order in the file so that welcome was after all of the path* entries, right before the path: '' entry.  My suspicion is that `http://localhost:4200/pathone/1` is now matching the plain `path: 'pathone'` entry and getting to the AuthGuard that way.  Since I'm not using the activated route to get the route parameters, it still works.  But if that's the case, all three urls should have gone to the welcome page, not just the first one.

As I said, I've eliminated the problem, but I don't think I've solved it because I don't understand why pathone was not working but pathtwo and paththree were.

Anyone have any idea of what was happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide AuthGuard code?

Comment: It'll be many way to effect the `Route`. I suggest you to enableTracing of your Angular Route, so you can debug it by yourself by modify importing your `RouteModule` in `app.module.ts` `imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true }) ]`

Comment: @LucaAngrisani - at the moment AuthGuard is just returning true in the CanLoad function.

paranaaan - great reminder.  I always forget that.